# Show if group has access to certain forms

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to understand how to write a query to distinguish if a user has access to certain form or not. I know what I am asking here looks easy but when I tried to implement it, it was whole different thing.
Maybe I am doing it wrong.

Before starting I want to mention the two tables names in start:

1. `sys_forms`,
2. `sys_forms_in_groups`

Also I am putting a SQL Fiddle link at the end.

Here is what I am trying to do.

[image]

If you can see the picture, on top dropdown box (it's a [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) dropdown), user selects the group and it will return GroupID, on the base of which I want to populated the below datatable. (DataTable is just showing groups, it's a dummy, but it will show forms, will fix it if problem is solved)

Now here the problem arise:

I want datatables to show all the forms available in `sys_forms` table in datatables but in actions columns of datatables only those checkboxes/switches should show granted which are available in the selected group(Group can be selected for select2 dropdown as said before).

`GroupID` is the column of other table `sys_forms_in_groups`.

All I want is that all the forms should show in the datatables no matter what group I choose, but Actions column in table should display `Granted` if the group has access to that particular form.

`forms_in_groups` is for showing if group has access to that certain form or not. For example:

```
    FormID  GroupID
------------------------------
    1          1
    2          1
    1          2
```

FormID `1` is available to both groupID `1` and `2`, on other hand FormID `2` is avaialable only to GroupID `1`.

Here is my [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1689a/2).

### Edit

The SQL Fiddle is not working, so putting screenshots here.

Table : sys_forms

[image]

Table : sys_forms_in_groups

[image]

I have tried this query, but it only returns forms for the selected group, where I want that all forms should show but they must show granted in Actions Columns on checkboxes/switchButtons

```
SELECT * FROM (`sys_forms`) INNER JOIN `sys_forms_in_groups` 
ON `sys_forms_in_groups`.`FormID` = `sys_forms`.`FormID` WHERE `GroupID` = 1;
```

Comment: Not read it all yet — but it looks like a brilliant example of a question. Well done.

Comment: @matrixdevuk
Thankyou sir.

Comment: — The SQLFIDDLE site is being a douche... not loading the fiddle properly.

Comment: @matrixdevuk
Ok, wait sir, i will find another way to display my tables and columns.

Comment: You might have to do `WHERE \`sys_forms_in_groups\`.\`GroupID\``

Comment: Also, you'd have: `SELECT * FROM \`sys_forms\``

Comment: @matrixdevuk
Sorry, i didn't understood. i already have tried where condition for GroupID as you can see in the query in the end of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Problem Solved and working perfectly fine, but after solving that problem i found out there is an other issue i didnt think of, but thats another matter. xD.
However, It was a little rough way to solve but i got what i wanted.

Here is how i did it,

I first needed to update my `select` query to,

```
SELECT f.FormID
     , f.FormName
     , f.FormCIPath
     , MAX(g.IsMenuLink) AS IsMenuLink
     , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT g.GroupID ORDER BY g.GroupID) AS GroupIDs
  FROM `sys_forms` f 
  JOIN `sys_forms_in_groups` g
    ON g.FormID = f.FormID
   AND g.GroupID IN (1,2)
 GROUP BY f.formID
```

Here you can see it will return all the forms which belongs to group 1 and group 2 but in a way that 1 and 2 will be in same column separated by comma.

Here how it shows now.
[image]

I am not a very complex query master so i am very much grateful to stackoverflow community to help me with the query. As i wanted to join both results to show in comma separated value.

After the MysQL the jquery work was not much difficult, i only sent the group ID for which i wanted the result to show in table. and there i got this result in return where i separate the GroupIDs with javascript split function and i get my groups.

Thankyou again everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're, incorrectly, trying to offload the issue onto MySQL.

It's not MySQL's job to render the forms and show whether a selected group has access to a specific form. That will fall onto your rendering of the page; using Select2 in this case.

You just want to retrieve all forms, then show whether the selected group has access to a specific form. That comes down to some Javascript that makes that check for you and displays it properly.

If you want to return all forms, the query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM (`sys_forms`) INNER JOIN `sys_forms_in_groups`
ON `sys_forms_in_groups`.`FormID` = `sys_forms`.`FormID`;
```

If you only want the forms that group 1 has access to, the query would be just as you have it:

```
SELECT * FROM (`sys_forms`) INNER JOIN `sys_forms_in_groups` 
ON `sys_forms_in_groups`.`FormID` = `sys_forms`.`FormID` WHERE `GroupID` = 1;
```

I didn't do a lot of digging into Select2, so I can't really help you in that aspect.

Comment: As i stated in top of my question, i thought it would be easy in start but when i started work on this, i knew its not that easy as i thought.
No, Javascript can only ON and OFF the switch button, but who will tell javascript to which Switch to ON or which switch to OFF?

Answer (score 0):

What I can see from your database schema, an inner join is the correct choice here based on the data you are looking for. The only issue I can see is in the WHERE clause. Seems that it may try to look for `GroupID` in the `sys_forms` table, so try specifying.

```
SELECT * FROM (`sys_forms`) INNER JOIN `sys_forms_in_groups` 
ON `sys_forms_in_groups`.`FormID` = `sys_forms`.`FormID` WHERE
`sys_forms_in_groups`.`GroupID` = 1;
```